# How can I calculate plasma temperature from particle density per energy histogram?

Tags: thermodynamics, plasma-physics

I want to know the temperature of electron plasma whose data has been generated via particle in cell simulation. My professor said if I have histogram of electron density by kinetic energy, then I can get temperature of the electron plasma when I apply the log on density. He also mentioned slope of log applied histogram for calculation. I have tried to find out what is that method, but I couldn't find any reference from it. Does anybody know about this?

I need to change my lab and advisor before the september ends so I need to organize what I have done as soon as possible for contancting other labs. And thank you for your helps.

Comment: It sounds like he assumes the distribution is an isotropic Maxwellian, so the log of the function will consist of the log of n (number density) minus the log the thermal speed plus the exponent terms plus some constants.  If you know n and E (energy), then you should be able to back out the thermal speed and then invert to get temperature (assuming it's actually Maxwellian).

Comment: Then, what if there are too many particles at E=0 so that peak checking for the distribution is not available? Just fitting the curve is the answer?

Comment: Choose a different reference frame ;)